# Using Varargs, can I assign values to variables based on the variable name?

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, variadic-functions

I am trying to pass a variable number of arguments into a constructor, because not all of the values will always be required, and empty values are okay. Can I make it such that I can pass the variables in, in any order, and have them assign to their corresponding variables in the class correctly?

Few things to note in my case is that the variables in the class are Serialized; the values are either a String, an Integer, a boolean, or a Date; and the values passed into the constructor will always match their corresponding class values (If the value in the class is an Integer, an Integer will always be passed in for that value, not a String.parseInt(), for example)

```
Class Foo {
  @SerializedName("id")
  private Integer id;

  @SerializeName("name")
  private String name;

  @SerializedName("isFoo")
  private Date isFoo;

  public Foo (Object... args){
  }
}
```

In the constructor I want to be able to ask if whatever object name matches a variable in the class, to assign it to that variable. So if one of the Object's passed is an Integer named id, is there a way to match it to id? It should be able to be matched in a few cases:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(id, name) //In this case, the bool would be null
Foo foo2 = new Foo(name, id, isFoo) //Here the Integer is second, but should still be able to be passed in correctly
```

I think this can be solved via Reflection but I am not sure how. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Objects don't have names. Only variables have names. The variable name used in the caller is unknown (and irrelevant) for the callee. All that you receive is an array of objects. Pass three arguments to your constructor, and pass null if you want one of the arguments to be null.

Comment: I think your goal is to avoid having cluttered constructor overloads. I'd recommend you change the whole design to a [fluent builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer your actual question below, but answering the underlying desire of the question, you're probably looking for the Builder pattern:

```
Foo foo = new Foo.Builder().id(id).name(name).build();
Foo foo = new Foo.Builder().name(name).id(id).isFoo(isFoo).build();
```

It's one of the original Gang of Four patterns.

(In the above I made `Builder` a nested class within `Foo`, as the builder class and the thing it builds tend to be intimately related. But that's not necessary, it's just one way it's done.)

---

> ...can I assign values to variables based on the variable name?

No. The *variables* are not passed to your method. The *value* contained in the variables is read from them, and *that value* is passed to your method. By the time it gets to your method, there is no connection whatsoever back to the variable the value came from (if, in fact, it came from a variable).

In your specific example, since each of them has a distinct type, you *could* check each of the entries in `args` to see what its type is and work from that, but it would be fairly odd and I wouldn't recommend it.

Emphasizing that **I wouldn't recommend it**, that would look like:

```
for (Object arg : args) {
    if (arg instanceof Integer) {
        this.id = (Integer)arg;
    } else if (arg instanceof String) {
        this.name = (String)arg;
    } else if (arg instanceof Date) {
        this.isFoo = (Date)arg;
    }
}
```

But again, I wouldn't recommend it, and if I came across it in a code review I'd want a *really, really good justification* for it. :-)

Comment: Could I potentially use (key, value) pairs to match up the variable I want to assign it to to the value? So each value is in a Set with things like <"id", 1234>. If so, how would I go about matching those up?

Comment: I think the Builder pattern seems like the best way to do it. The problem I was encountering was if I ever needed to add another variable to the constructor I would have to refactor every constructor method, this way I can just add to the builder and the builders being used continue to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Hunter: Yup, that's one of the motivations for Builder. I don't know if GoF is as famous now as a decade ago, but I'm referring to [*Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* by Gamma, Helm, Johnson, and Vlissides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).